# std::vector move instead of swap to empty vector and deallocate storage

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Do I understand right that with introduction of move semantics in C++11, move can be used instead of swap-to-clear idiom in order to empty vector including storage deallocation?

```
std::vector<T>().swap( v );
// VS
v = std::move( std::vector<T>() );
```

Is the second approach guaranteed to work as the first one?

PS. As @MaximEgorushkin noted, there is no need in `std::move` above since r-value is assigned.

Comment: What do you mean _clear storage_, deallocation? The memory allocated with the temporary object will be deallocated after its lifetime, which ends after the `move()` call.

Comment: Why is this being down voted?

Comment: You confused it with `std::vector<T>(v).swap(v);` - trim the vector storage. `v = std::vector<T>()` worked in C++98 pretty much the same way.

Comment: why not `v.clear()`? It is definitely **clearer** :D

Comment: @CássioRenan `clear` is not guaranteed to release the memory the vector has acquired.

Comment: @NathanOliver Then use `shrink_to_fit()`...

Comment: @MaxLanghof That isn't guaranteed either.

Answer (score 4):

You probably confused it with `std::vector<T>(v).swap(v);` - trim the vector storage.

You do not need to call `std::move` when assigning an r-value though, just

```
v = std::vector<T>(v);
```

is enough.

Answer (score 4):

Just for perfect clarity, if all you want is for your vector to be *empty*, you can just use

```
v.clear();
```

Assuming you want it to release allocated storage, then move-assignment will work *in general*:

```
v = std::vector<T>();
```

(see that the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D) guarantees that the move steals the right-hand-side's allocation, which will have the desired effect).

Note the exception mentioned in the same documentation: if you have a non-propogating stateful allocator, you get an element-by-element move and no guarantee of what happens to the allocated storage.

In that case `v.shrink_to_fit()` may work, although it's a quality-of-implementation issue rather than a promise. Note that in this case the old [`swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap) technique wouldn't have worked either, so this is probably a good reason to avoid that sort of allocator.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you understand it correctly.

Note that it is possible that your implementation actually implements vector move semantics through swap semantics, meaning that your

```
v = std::vector<T>();
```

might end up being fully equivalent to the original swap.